# Java superinterfaces runtime difference Java 8 vs Java 9

Tags: java, reflection, java-8, overriding, java-11

I noticed a difference in the output of the following program when run with Java 8 and Java 9.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
public class OrderingTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServiceImpl service = new ServiceImpl();
        for (Method method : service.getClass().getMethods()) {
            for (Class<?> anInterface : method.getDeclaringClass().getInterfaces()) {
                try {
                    Method intfMethod = anInterface.getMethod(method.getName(), method.getParameterTypes());
                    System.out.println("intfMethod = " + intfMethod);
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) { }
            }
        }
    }
}

class ServiceImpl implements ServiceX {
    @Override
    public Foo getType() { return null; }
}

interface ServiceX extends ServiceA<Foo>, ServiceB { }
abstract class Goo { }
class Foo extends Goo { }

interface ServiceA<S> {
    S getType();
}
interface ServiceB {
    @java.lang.Deprecated
    Goo getType();
}
```

You can run both versions of java here:
https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler/

Java 8 outputs:

```
intfMethod = public abstract java.lang.Object ServiceA.getType()
intfMethod = public abstract java.lang.Object ServiceA.getType()
intfMethod = public abstract java.lang.Object ServiceA.getType()
```

Java 9 outputs:

```
intfMethod = public abstract Goo ServiceB.getType()
intfMethod = public abstract Goo ServiceB.getType()
intfMethod = public abstract Goo ServiceB.getType()
```

But when I reorder the super-interfaces to:

```
interface ServiceX extends ServiceB, ServiceA<Foo> { }
```

Then both versions of java output:

```
intfMethod = public abstract Goo ServiceB.getType()
intfMethod = public abstract Goo ServiceB.getType()
intfMethod = public abstract Goo ServiceB.getType()
```

I was wondering what is causing it? Is there a new java feature I am not aware of?

Java 8 documentation
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8

Java 9 documentation
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference seems to be in the implementation of `getMethod` API in use which is visible by the stated [documentation starting Java-9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-) :

> Within each such subset only the most specific methods are selected.
> Let method M be a method from a set of methods with same VM signature
> (return type, name, parameter types). M is most specific if there is
> no such method N != M from the same set, such that N is more specific
> than M. N is more specific than M if:
>
> a. N is declared by a class and M is declared by an interface; or
>
> b. N and M are both declared by classes
> or both by interfaces and N's declaring type is the same as or a
> subtype of M's declaring type (clearly, if M's and N's declaring types
> are the same type, then M and N are the same method).

While Java-8 follows up internally with `interfaceCandidates.getFirst()` (i.e. the order change matters here), the upgraded version seems to be working on the specific algorithm using `res.getMostSpecific()` before returning the method asked for.

Comment: As you said, the old Java version 8 https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk8-b120/jdk/src/share/classes/java/lang/Class.java calls getMethod0 which returns the first result but the Java v9 https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk9-b94/jdk/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Class.java makes a call to MethodArray.removeLessSpecifics()

Answer (score -4):

Answer moved from body of question:

---

The root cause was that java type erasure at compile time creates a bridge method with a return type of "Object", which is less specific than a return type of "Goo". Java 9 was given an update to the implementation of Class.getMethod() to change from returning the first defined interface's implementation to instead return the most specific implementation.

```
foo@bar:~$ javap ./ServiceImpl.class
Compiled from "OrderingTest.java"
class ServiceImpl implements ServiceX {
  ServiceImpl();
  public Foo getType();
  public java.lang.Object getType(); <== here
  public Goo getType();
}
```

The old functionality from Java 8 can be maintained in Java 9 by adding another interface which overrides the generic method with an API making it more specific. This will work with Java 9 as it did in Java 8.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
public class OrderingTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServiceImpl service = new ServiceImpl();
        for (Method method : service.getClass().getMethods()) {
            for (Class<?> anInterface : method.getDeclaringClass().getInterfaces()) {
                try {
                    Method intfMethod = anInterface.getMethod(method.getName(), method.getParameterTypes());
                    System.out.println("intfMethod = " + intfMethod);
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) { }
            }
        }
    }
}

class ServiceImpl implements ServiceX {
    @Override
    public Foo getType() { return new Foo(); }
}

interface ServiceX extends ServiceAA, ServiceB { }
abstract class Goo { }
class Foo extends Goo { }
interface ServiceAA extends ServiceA<Foo> {
    @Override
    Foo getType();
}
interface ServiceA<S> {
    S getType();
}
interface ServiceB {
    @java.lang.Deprecated
    Goo getType();
}
```